# Why doesn't Ubuntu One Music app (Android) recognise mp3 files uploaded via the U1 REST API?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, ubuntu-one-api

I've uploaded a few music files (.mp3 and .ogg, no DRM) via the Ubuntu One REST API. (I'm writing a python library that uses it.) The Ubuntu One Music app on my Android phone doesn't pick up on these files. (They do not appear in the library after requesting a Refresh, not even under "Unknown artist".) Similar files uploaded via the official client, on the other hand, get picked up immediately.

Is this somehow expected behaviour, and I'm just missing the explanation? And how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most certainly not expected behaviour. We're looking in to why it might happen. Can you confirm a few things for me?

1. the files, when uploaded from the REST API and then downloaded from the website, have not been corrupted or altered?
2. the filesizes of the REST-API-uploaded files are as you'd expect on the website?
3. is the mimetype of the REST-API-uploaded MP3s *audio/mpeg* ?

That last one is the important one. Use "More" to show details of a file on the website to see its mimetype. Uploads through Ubuntu One guess the mimetype for you if you don't specify it. The REST API trusts you more and uses what you specify (and chooses a neutral type if you do not; specifically, it won't guess audio/mpeg for mp3s).

[image: using More to expand a file on the website]

Comment: also, I'm not sure if you're aware of https://launchpad.net/restful-u1 but it's an existing Python client for the REST API; cool to see another one, though, if restful-u1 doesn't meet your needs. I'd love to chat about what you're planning :-)

Comment: Problem between chair and keyboard: I wasn't setting the mime type correctly on the upload. Now working beautifully ^_^

Comment: As for the existing client... I didn't find it. I saw https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntuone-control-tower/ubuntuone-file-storage-api/trunk which doesn't have file upload capability, and stopped looking. (My project is also an excuse to get comfortable with python packaging and doc tools, so the effort isn't totally wasted, but after a quick glance it looks like the restful-u1 client will do everything I need.)